# How do I get an swf player to work in Linux?

Tags: linux, flash, apache, .htaccess, mp3

I have a site where I need to play a mp3 file specific to the [listing](http://www.billpelton.com/sale.php?saleid=227).  The file needs to play in the same browser window (instructions from the client).  I found a js/swf player ([WordPress Audio Payer standalone version](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/)) that works on my local machine (Windows running WAMP), but when I send it to the live server (Linux with Apache), it buffers continually and doesn't play.

I found a website that said I need to modify the htaccess file to recognize flash media.  This is what it said to add, and I did that with no improvement.

```
# Macromedia tells the server how to deal with swf files
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to monitor the traffic (using Firebug or Chrome development tools)? For example this issue may be related to incorrect [Crossdomain Policy](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html) on your server. You can easily detect it by searching for crossdomain.xml in network traffic list.